# My Computer Takes Too Long To Shut Down - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have a Lenovo Yoga Windows 10 computer. When I try to shut down my computer, it  can be stuck on shut down loading screen for 1+ hours. I try to hold the power button, but it just puts it on sleep mode. When I click it again, it just shows the shut down loading screen again. I know that I had closed down every program that was open then I shut it down and went to bed. The next morning, it was still shutting down. 
This happened a few times already.

What should I do next time this happens?

Comment: It could be performing updates, it might be malware.... more information is needed.

Comment: Try holding sown shift while clicking "Shutdown", this will force a full Windows 10 shutdown.  If you don't use shift (and your hardware supports it) it will use a fast shutdown, where it suspends certain parts of Windows instead of shutting them of, to speed up the next boot.

Comment: It could bt that you have too much junk on your computer, get and use one of the clean-up programs( norton will do a good job.).  Check the error log and see if some piece of hardware is malfunctioning.

Comment: See https://www.howtogeek.com/281863/how-to-make-windows-shut-down-faster/ for some things to try